# Parse iOS SDK not sending application Id

Tags: parse-platform

I'm testing out deploying my own parse server following the steps in the Parse Server Guide. I've got the server up and running and have been able to create and fetch objects via curl. I built a simple iOS app using the Parse SDK (1.14.2). I've initialized the SDK with the app id and server url as described in the Parse Server Guide. When I try to make requests, I get back unauthorized from the server. Digging further, I noticed that the SDK is not sending the application id header to the server. I modified the SDK to send the application id header and everything works. Am I missing a configuration step somewhere?

Comment: Can you post your initialization code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not passing the ClientKey. In swift 3 you would pass it like this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
 // Init Parse
        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = PARSE_APP_KEY
            $0.clientKey = PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
            $0.server = PARSE_SERVER_URL
            $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true

        }
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

If you are falling when trying to test `CloudCode`, then its because your parse-server is not passing the `Javascript key`. So just make sure you initialize the server to do so if this issue is related to Parse.Cloud function.